# Zip or create key-value pairs from two lists of lists

Tags: python

I have the following MWE:

```
token_uniqueness_sparse = pd.DataFrame({'token_a': [0.1, 0.0],
                                        'token_b': [0.0, 0.2],
                                        'token_c': [0.3, 0.0]
                                       }
                                      )
sf_fake = pd.DataFrame({'items': [ ['token_a', 'token_c'],
                                   ['token_b']],
                        'rcol': [1,2]
                       })

token_uniqueness_dense = (token_uniqueness_sparse
         .apply(lambda x: list(x[x.ne(0)]), axis=1)
         .to_frame('output_column'))

token_uniqueness_dense 
output_column
0   [0.1, 0.3]
1   [0.2]
```

I'm trying to combine the two lists of lists such that I get key-value pairs and can sort the keys by the value. For example:

```
{token_a: 0.1, token_c: 0.3}
{token_b: 0.2}
```

If there's a better/smarter way than the way I'm asking for, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one way:

```
sf_fake=sf_fake.explode('items').set_index('items').T.reset_index(drop=True)
'''
items  token_a  token_c  token_b
0            1        1        2
'''
#for example, token_a takes the value in index number 1 in token_uniqueness_sparse df

final={i:token_uniqueness_sparse[i].iloc[sf_fake[i].iloc[0] -1] for i in token_uniqueness_sparse.columns} #token_uniqueness_sparse' index starting 0. Thats why subtract 1.

# output: {'token_a': 0.1, 'token_b': 0.2, 'token_c': 0.3}
```

If you want to a dictionary for each row:

```
sf_fake['dicts']=sf_fake.apply(lambda x: {i:token_uniqueness_sparse[i][x['rcol']-1] for i in x['items']},axis=1)
'''
                items  rcol                             dicts
0  [token_a, token_c]     1  {'token_a': 0.1, 'token_c': 0.3}
1           [token_b]     2                  {'token_b': 0.2}
'''

#or get as a list
print(sf_fake['dicts'].to_list())

# [{'token_a': 0.1, 'token_c': 0.3}, {'token_b': 0.2}]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm looking to have a dictionary for each row, so I'd need two dictionaries. `{token_a: 0.1, token_c: 0.3}` for the first row then `{token_b: 0.2}` for the second row. @Bushmaster

Comment: Okey. We can do this in single line. Please check edited answer.